# rpm related security information

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I'm referring to the following link to embed some 
extra security related information into rpms.

https://www.redhat.com/security/data/metrics/

I've somewhat similar requirement for XenServer where
I would like to embed some fix data for CVE/XSA into the rpm
which I'm building for Xen or kernel. This metrics link does
provide the feature but it's actually created/consumed by
rpms built by RH. Is there a way to harness this feature?

How does this xml (mapping to RHSA to CVE xml data) is consumed,
parsed and processed?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of seldom used tags (DISTURL, BUGURL) that could be used to reference an external remote CVE package tracking database that are likely preserved in RHEL.

The mapping from RHSA -> CVE mapping is handled outside of rpm and build systems within changelogs and comments, largely because CVE's and fixes are done long after the original package is/was built.